# Chrome Command Line Switches in Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I had a .bat file that I was using to launch Google Chrome in Kiosk mode and allowed Chrome to read files from the local drive as follows:

```
start Chrome "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files --kiosk
```

This worked in Win 7 and 8.x. When I updated recently to Windows 10, this doesn't work anymore. Not entirely sure if this is Win 10 or the latest Chrome Win release. I can live without kiosk, but I need the allow-file-access-from files, because my localized "app" shows 3D objects via three.js.

I think it may be a Win 10 thing, because I am running a similar Applescript/shells script on my Mac and this still works with the latest Chrome Mac OS X.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. I turned off Windows Defender and performed a restart. Ran my .bat file: kiosk mode and allow-file-access-from-files now works. Turned back on Windows Defender and the .bat file still works. So my best guest is that all Chrome tasks were not off (even though I went in Task Manager and quit out of everything) because of its interaction with WinDefender. Or WinDefender was blocking the initial run of this script.

Comment: I will verify by trying this with my desktop work PC after the weekend.